# Position array text in PHP GD on middle of specific part of image

Tags: php, gd

I have an array of a string to fit on a page, i managed to center it horizontal now i need to do that vertical in a specific part of image.

```
     $imgWidth = 240;
    $imgHeight = 900;

    $IMG = imagecreatetruecolor($imgWidth,$imgHeight);
    $font_type_bold = '/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf';
    $background = imagecolorallocate($IMG, 78,129,154);
    $text_white = imagecolorallocate($IMG, 255,255,255);
    $IMG = imagecreatetruecolor($imgWidth,$imgHeight);
    $max_lenght_of_title = 15;
    $special_issue_name_mod="This is some example text to be put on the page and split into array to fit he width of frame";
    $text = explode("\n", wordwrap($special_issue_name_mod, $max_lenght_of_title));
    $line_height=30;
    imageline($IMG, 0, 500, 240, 500, $text_white);
    imageline($IMG, 0, 100, 240, 100, $text_white);
    for($i=0;$i<count($text);$i++) {
        $font_size_si_name_horizontal = 21;
        //Center the text
        $size = imagettfbbox(20, 0, $font_type_bold, $text[$i]);
        $long_text = $size[2] + $size[0];
        $posx = ($imgWidth - $long_text) / 2;

        imagettftext($IMG, $font_size_si_name_horizontal, 0, $posx - 5, 150+ $line_height + $line_height * $i , $text_white, $font_type_bold, $text[$i]);
    }
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($IMG);
    imagecolordeallocate($IMG, $text_color );
    imagecolordeallocate($IMG, $background );
```

The result is this and i need it to be in specific part of page, for example selected one

[image]

So how can i make this to not be the fixed middle but adjustive one depending on what part of page the text will be.

Note: Text can be longer, so thats the main problem. Depending on lenght of text the title should be in the middle

Comment: Are you saying about the text to be shown vertically middle?

Comment: Yes vertically middle, but not middle of whole height but marked part of page. Middle of marked part

Comment: Try with this
     imagecopyresampled($new, $image, $margin_x, 0, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $width, $height);
     imagejpeg($new, $save, 100);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to solve this

```
 $middle_of_page = 350;
 for($i=0;$i<count($text);$i++) { 
     $middle_of_page = $middle_of_page - 21;
}
imagettftext($IMG, $font_size_si_name_horizontal, 0, $posx - 5,  $middle_of_page+$line_height + $line_height * $i , $text_white, $font_type_bold, $text[$i]);
```

With the $middle_of_page part i regulate the point where text with array size of one will be, and then i just remove by font size of 21 for every $i that stands for array size of string.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $imgWidth = 240;
    $imgHeight = 900;
    $IMG = imagecreatetruecolor($imgWidth,$imgHeight);
    $font_type_bold = 'BioRhyme/BioRhyme-Regular.ttf';
    $background = imagecolorallocate($IMG, 78,129,154);
    $text_white = imagecolorallocate($IMG, 255,255,255);

    $IMG = imagecreatetruecolor($imgWidth,$imgHeight);
    $max_lenght_of_title = 15;
    $special_issue_name_mod="This is some example text to be put on the page and split into array to fit he width of frame";
    $text = explode("\n", wordwrap($special_issue_name_mod, $max_lenght_of_title));
    $line_height=30;
    $vert = ($imgHeight/5);
    for($i=0;$i<count($text);$i++) {
        $font_size_si_name_horizontal = 21;
        //Center the text
        $size = imagettfbbox(20, 0, $font_type_bold, $text[$i]);
        $long_text = $size[2] + $size[0];
        $posx = ($imgWidth - $long_text) / 2;

        imagettftext($IMG, $font_size_si_name_horizontal, 0, $posx - 5, $vert+ $line_height + $line_height * $i , $text_white, $font_type_bold, $text[$i]);
    }
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($IMG);
    imagecolordeallocate($IMG, $text_color );
    imagecolordeallocate($IMG, $background );
?>
```

I have added `$vert = ($imgHeight/5);` and put into `imagettftext()` for dynamically calculted vertical Y index!

Comment: This didn't help, your method is only for one possibility, if the text is longer or shorter string, its not centered in the desired part of image.

Comment: Your code doesn't contain output as you have shown here. it means output doesn't have a block with a red border and different background color. First, implement that and update.

Comment: That was only for description, now i updated that so you could understand the problem.